# Jedis ClassNotFound and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, redis, cytoscape.js

I developed a plugin for a data visualization tool. Now I want to use redis inside of it. When I try the below redis code which I took from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_java.htm) in an other project(not inside my plugin) it works well.

```
//Connecting to Redis server on localhost 
  Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost"); 
  System.out.println("Connection to server sucessfully"); 
  //check whether server is running or not 
  System.out.println("Server is running: "+jedis.ping());
```

But when I use Jedis inside my plugin I got `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Jedis` and `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Jedis` errors. In order to install my plugin to this data visualization tool. I need to create a jar file which I do and it works well without adding jedit parts.

I am using IntelliJ Idea and I created an artifact and build id it from build - build artifact tab inside the top menu. And I also added jedis jar file as dependency in pom.xml (this is a maven project), I added it as library from project structure and I added jedis jar file as extracted directory and as library as well from the artifacts tab of project structure menu. And then I added jedis jar file to my project .classpath file like below:

```
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources/jedis-2.1.0-sources.jar" including="**/*.java"/>
```

So when I open my jar file I can see that there is Jedis.java file inside "redis/clients/jedis" path. And there is also jedis jar file inside root path of my jar file. But even that it does not works. It gives the error above at the **runtime**. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loooong researches and "experiments" I solved it. Here is the part that I added my pom.xml in order to get rid of this. And I also create jar file with the "mvn package" command, not from the IntelliJ IDEA interface.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8.0_161</source>
                <target>1.8.0_161</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>App.CytoVisProject</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```